# How can I monitor network usage per website in Firefox v69+?

Tags: firefox-addon, monitoring, bandwidth

I have Firefox v69 on Windows 10. Windows 10 network monitor only shows network usage and bandwidth for the past 30 seconds or so. I'd like to see, within Firefox preferably, which pages or domains use the most bandwidth for all time.

1. Windows 10 data monitor (different from 30 second network traffic mentioned above) only shows total data usage. I'd like to see usage by website or domain, per day.
2. I've done some googling but most answers are outdated and the FF addons I find do not exist anymore. I've also found some OS network monitors but those do not break down traffic by web page or domain.

Thanks!